# TYPO3 error configuring extension "sphinx"

Tags: configuration, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I've installed latest `sphinx` version 2.3.1.
I have TYPO3 CMS 6.2.19.

Before `sphinx` can be used it must be configured. Now in `sphinx` configuration area I click on `Sphinx 1.4.5`. After some time I get following message:

```
Sphinx 1.4.5 has been downloaded.  

Could not extract Sphinx 1.4.5:  
Could not extract 3rd-party libraries for Sphinx:

Archive: /opt/lampp/htdocs/cms1/typo3temp/sphinx-contrib.zip
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 596: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!  

Could not find a compatible version of Pygments
```

I could debug this extension and found out it crashes at following command:

```
CommandUtility::exec("'/usr/bin/unzip' '/opt/lampp/htdocs/cms1/typo3temp/sphinx-contrib.zip' -d '/opt/lampp/htdocs/cms1/uploads/tx_sphinx/sphinx-contrib' 2>&1", $out, $returnValue);
```

If I execute it from a php-one-line script I get following message:

```
lchmod (file attributes) error: Function not implemented
```

Does anybody understand what is wrong with it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've found a workaround myself: it were libraries. So I had to preload another versions.

All in all, the way is: in the file where `unzip` is called (Setup.php) in the function `unarchive` add `LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1:/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` before `unzip` command. Now it looks as follows:

```
$cmd = 'LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1:/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 ' . $unzip . ' ' . escapeshellarg($archiveFileName) ...
```

And yes, it is not the best solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: I added the issue to the issue tracker of the extension at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77449. As the extension is maintained, I am sure the author will react there and provide a fix or at least a comment

Comment: The point is: the author has already corrected this issue some releases ago. I've found his answer in bugtracker. Eigher it was forgotten in the current version or it slipped in again.